# restart a service after device has been mounted

Tags: mount, systemd

Is it possible to *restart* a systemd-service `A` from another unit `B`?
the service `A` (to be restarted) is supposed to run, regardless of the status of `B`, but once `B` becomes active (or inactive) it needs to be notified (e.g. by means of a restart/reload)

AFAIK, the `Before=` and `After=` directives do not really help here, as they require both `A` and `B` to run synchronously.

## background

What I'm really trying to achieve is to have `snmpd` monitor a couple of partitions, some of which are not available at all times.
So I was thinking of writing a `sometimes-partition.mount` unit that would restart the `snmpd.service`.